When adding more fields to my custom login and wanting to capture the values ​it does not work
I have a custom login page that apart from the username and password I have the document type field and remember, how can I capture them in my personalized CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider to be able to add one more validation apart from the password. Add this filter to my Spring Authorizathion Server configuration and now I always get the error org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorizationDeniedException: Access Denied when trying to log in from my custom login page
Login Page image
Versions
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<java.version>21</java.version>
<spring-security.version>6.4.1</spring-security.version>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
</dependency>

Oauth2Config.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Oauth2Config {

    private final UsuarioService usuarioService;

    public Oauth2Config(UsuarioService usuarioService) {
        this.usuarioService = usuarioService;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                                      RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository,
                                                                      OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService,
                                                                      OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService authorizationConsentService)
            throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        OAuth2TokenGenerator<? extends OAuth2Token> tokenGenerator = OAuth2ConfigurerUtils.getTokenGenerator(http);
        Function<OidcUserInfoAuthenticationContext, OidcUserInfo> userInfoMapper = new CustomUserInfoMapper(usuarioService);

        // @formatter:off
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc((oidc) -> oidc
                        .userInfoEndpoint((userInfo) -> userInfo
                                .userInfoMapper(userInfoMapper)
                        )
                )
                .authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpoint ->
                        authorizationEndpoint
                                .authenticationProviders(
                                        customProvidersConsumer(registeredClientRepository, authorizationService,
                                                authorizationConsentService, tokenGenerator)
                                )
                );

        http
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                          AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/css/**", "/imagenes/**", "/iconos/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(authenticationConfiguration)), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new JasyptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider customDaoAuthenticationProvider() {
        CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<List<AuthenticationProvider>> customProvidersConsumer(RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository,
                                                                          OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService,
                                                                          OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService authorizationConsentService,
                                                                          OAuth2TokenGenerator<? extends OAuth2Token> tokenGenerator) {

        OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider defaultCodeProvider =
                new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider(registeredClientRepository, authorizationService, authorizationConsentService);
        AuthenticationProvider customCodeProvider = new CustomAuthorizationCodeRequestProvider(defaultCodeProvider);

        OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider defaultClientCredentialsProvider =
                new OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider(authorizationService, tokenGenerator);
        AuthenticationProvider customClientCredentialProvider = new CustomClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider(defaultClientCredentialsProvider);

        return providers -> {
            providers.addFirst(customCodeProvider);
            providers.addFirst(customClientCredentialProvider);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

     @Bean
    public JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
        return new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcOperations);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationService jdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations, RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
        JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService = new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcOperations, registeredClientRepository);

        ClassLoader classLoader = JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.class.getClassLoader();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModules(new CoreJackson2Module());
        objectMapper.registerModules(SecurityJackson2Modules.getModules(classLoader));
        objectMapper.registerModule(new OAuth2AuthorizationServerJackson2Module());
        objectMapper.addMixIn(CustomUserDetails.class, CustomUserDetailsMixin.class);

        JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper rowMapper =
                new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper(registeredClientRepository);
        rowMapper.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

        authorizationService.setAuthorizationRowMapper(rowMapper);

        return authorizationService;
    }


    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService authorizationConsentService(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
                                                                         RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
        return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService(jdbcOperations, registeredClientRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    NimbusJwtEncoder nimbusJwtEncoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource);
    }


    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }
}

CustomAuthenticationFilter.java
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        String tipoDocumento = request.getParameter("tipoDocumento");
        tipoDocumento = tipoDocumento != null ? tipoDocumento.trim() : "";
        String recordar = request.getParameter("recordar");
        recordar = recordar != null ? recordar.trim() : "of";

        request.getSession().setAttribute("tipoDocumento", tipoDocumento);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("recordar", recordar);

        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
    }

}

CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider.java
public class CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
    private static final String USER_NOT_FOUND_PASSWORD = "userNotFoundPassword";
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private volatile String userNotFoundEncodedPassword;
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private UserDetailsPasswordService userDetailsPasswordService;
    private CompromisedPasswordChecker compromisedPasswordChecker;

    public CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider() {
        this(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder());
    }

    public CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            this.logger.debug("Failed to authenticate since no credentials provided");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        } else {
            // TODO: ADD DOCUMENT TYPE LOGIC
            CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = (CustomUserDetails) userDetails;
            String presentedPassword = customUserDetails.getSalt() + authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            String secret = customUserDetails.getSecret();
            if (!this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, secret)) {
                this.logger.debug("Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value");
                throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
            }
        }
    }

    protected void doAfterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.notNull(this.userDetailsService, "A UserDetailsService must be set");
    }

    protected final UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        this.prepareTimingAttackProtection();

        try {
            UserDetails loadedUser = this.getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (loadedUser == null) {
                throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation");
            } else {
                return loadedUser;
            }
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException var4) {
            UsernameNotFoundException ex = var4;
            this.mitigateAgainstTimingAttack(authentication);
            throw ex;
        } catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException var5) {
            InternalAuthenticationServiceException ex = var5;
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception var6) {
            Exception ex = var6;
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    protected Authentication createSuccessAuthentication(Object principal, Authentication authentication, UserDetails user) {
        String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        boolean isPasswordCompromised = this.compromisedPasswordChecker != null && this.compromisedPasswordChecker.check(presentedPassword).isCompromised();
        if (isPasswordCompromised) {
            throw new CompromisedPasswordException("The provided password is compromised, please change your password");
        } else {
            boolean upgradeEncoding = this.userDetailsPasswordService != null && this.passwordEncoder.upgradeEncoding(user.getPassword());
            if (upgradeEncoding) {
                String newPassword = this.passwordEncoder.encode(presentedPassword);
                user = this.userDetailsPasswordService.updatePassword(user, newPassword);
            }

            return super.createSuccessAuthentication(principal, authentication, user);
        }
    }

    private void prepareTimingAttackProtection() {
        if (this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword == null) {
            this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword = this.passwordEncoder.encode("userNotFoundPassword");
        }

    }

    private void mitigateAgainstTimingAttack(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
            String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword);
        }

    }

    public void setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        Assert.notNull(passwordEncoder, "passwordEncoder cannot be null");
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword = null;
    }

    protected PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return this.passwordEncoder;
    }

    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    protected UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
        return this.userDetailsService;
    }

    public void setUserDetailsPasswordService(UserDetailsPasswordService userDetailsPasswordService) {
        this.userDetailsPasswordService = userDetailsPasswordService;
    }

    public void setCompromisedPasswordChecker(CompromisedPasswordChecker compromisedPasswordChecker) {
        this.compromisedPasswordChecker = compromisedPasswordChecker;
    }
}

This is my log ouput
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19g4rVaiV_kRjS8PTkVXUQF5CzieDGvBq/view?usp=drive_link
I need to access the values ​​of the document type fields and remember in my CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider
